# Counterexample for $R(4,4) \neq 8$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

I try to find a counterexample for $R(4,4)\neq 8$. (R is the Ramsey-number).

I drew a graph with 8 vedges and I coloured all edges $(v_i,v_j)$ with $i-j =\pm 2,4,6$ in the same colour (for example in red). But then I'll find a $K_4$ with $(v_1,v_3,v_5,v_7)$, which is definitely not a counterexample.

Perhaps someone can help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added the ramsey-theory tag. The stronger result $R(4,3)>8$ is shown here: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey43.shtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to see that $R(4,4) > 9$ is to take three disconnected copies of $K_3$:s. Of course this is very far from being optimal, since the true value is $R(4,4)=18$.

Comment: Ah, of corse. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a proof that $R(4,4)>17$ which I "borrowed" from [cut the knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey44.shtml).  We take the $17$-vertex [circulant graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_graph) with edges of distances $\{1,2,4,8\}$ as the red edges and distances $\{3,5,6,7\}$ as the blue edges.

So we have the red edges:

[image: Red edges]

and the blue edges:

[image: Blue edges]

Since the graph is [vertex transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph) it is sufficient to check that the neighbourhood of some fixed vertex does not contain an induced monochromatic $K_3$.

We check the monochromatic neighbourhoods:

[image: Red neighbourhood]

and

[image: Blue neighbourhood]

and find there are no triangles (ignoring the dotted edges).