# Subsets with numbers such that $a+b = c$

Tags: number-theory

> The set $\{1,2,\ldots,49\}$ is divided into three subsets. Prove that at least one of these subsets contains three different numbers $a,b,c$ such that $a+b = c$.

Assume not, so that $\{1,2,\ldots,49\}$ can be partitioned into three weakly sum-free subsets $A,B,C$. One of the subsets, say $A$, must contain at least $\left[\dfrac{49}{3}\right]+1 = 17$ elements. Then $A$ contains elements $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_{17}$. Now consider the  differences $a_{i}-a_{j}$ where $i > j$. There are at least $\binom{17}{2} = 136$ such differences and they are all in $\{1,2,\ldots,48\}$. So then there must exist $i_1 > i_2$ and $i_3  > i_4$ with $(i_1,i_2) \neq (i_3,i_4)$ such that $a_{i_1}-a_{i_2}= a_{i_3}-a_{i_4} $.

I am trying to figure out how to get a contradiction from this. I can rewrite the last one to be $(a_{i_1}-a_{i_3})+a_{i_4} = a_{i_2}$, but I don't see an immediate contradiction from here. How should I try to get the contradiction?

Comment: The $49$ can be replaced by $24$.  See P. Blanchard, F. Harary and R. Reis, [Partitions into sum-free sets](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g7/g7.Abstract.html), Integers: electronic journal of combinatorial number theory, 6. 2006.

Comment: Your approach won't work, because in fact you *can* find a 17 element subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,49\}$ that is weakly sum-free.  For example, $\bigcup_{0\leq k < 17}  \{3k+1\} \cup \{2\}$ is weakly sum-free and has 18 elements.  So you will need to use the fact that when this is constructed, one of the other two sets has to have a sum.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That is for sum-free parts, not weakly sum-free parts.

Comment: Looks weakly sum-free to me: 
"Theorem 1. For any $m > 0$, there is a finite natural number $h = h(m)$ so that for any finite
coloring $\pi: N_h \to N_m$ there exist $x \ne y$ so that $\{x, y, x + y\}$ is monochromatic. Moreover,
$h(1) = 3$, $h(2) = 9$, $h(3) = 24$, and $h(4) = 67$."

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why isn't $49$ one of the numbers?

Comment: Beginning with $49$ and working backwards to $25$ the numbers may be tossed into any of the three piles with reckless abandon. But beginning with $24$ one will have to begin being selective. I presume this relates to @RobertIsrael 's point.

Comment: Blanchard, Harary and Reis say there is no partition of $\{1,\ldots,24\}$ into three weakly sum-free sets, and $24$ is best possible.  It may be easy to prove that there is no partition of $\{1,\ldots,49\}$ into three weakly sum-free sets: I don't immediately see a proof though.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about [Schur numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchurNumber.html), we are simply asked to prove a lower bound for something similar to $S(3)$. 
Let $A,B,C$ be our partition of $[1,49]$, and let we give a colour in $\{0,1,2\}$ to every element $n\in[1,49]$, according to $n\in A$, $n\in B$ or $n\in C$. Let we consider the complete graph $K_{49}$ and let we give to the edge $xy$ the same colour of $|x-y|$: a monochromatic $K_4$ ensures the presence of a Schur triple in $A,B$ or $C$ with distinct terms, and the problem boils down to estimating a [Ramsey number](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey333.shtml), $R(4,4,4)$. Since [$R(4,4)=18$](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/Ramsey44.shtml) (also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142105/ramsey-number-r4-4)) and [$R(3,3,3)=17$](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~ploh/docs/math/mop2013/graph-theory-red-soln.pdf), the claim easily follows from $49=3\cdot 17-2$.